# JQuery UI Datpicker excluding icons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, datepicker

I'm working on an application and am using jQuery UI Datepicker widget. But I do not want to use the default icons from the datepicker and want the Next and Prev text in place of the icons that is visible when I remove the icon classes.

I'm currently on a code like this:

```
$("#datePicker").on("click", function(){
    $('.ui-icon.ui-icon-circle-triangle-w').removeClass('ui-icon ui-icon-circle-triangle-w');
})
```

where datePicker is the id for the date field.

This works fine when I initially open the datepicker. But, when I click the Prev button, the icons appear again. How can I persist with the Next/Prev even when I switch the month view.

Comment: Please provide us with a working sample of your date picker so we can check for a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go with the solution http://jsfiddle.net/8w8v9/3308/

```js
$(function(){
    
    $('#thedate').datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
        altField: '#thealtdate',
        altFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
        prevText: "Prev",
        nextText: "Next"
    });
    
    replaceIcon = function(){
   $('.ui-icon.ui-icon-circle-triangle-w').parent().removeAttr('class').attr('class', 'updatedClassLeft');
      $('.ui-icon.ui-icon-circle-triangle-w').removeAttr('class');
      
      $('.ui-icon.ui-icon-circle-triangle-e').parent().removeAttr('class').attr('class', 'updatedClassRight');
      $('.ui-icon.ui-icon-circle-triangle-e').removeAttr('class');
      
    }
    
   
    $("#thedate").on("click", function(){
     replaceIcon();
   });
    
    $(document).on('click','.updatedClassLeft, .updatedClassRight',function(){
     replaceIcon();

    });
});
```

```css
.updatedClassLeft{
    position: absolute;
    top: 8px;
    left: 0px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.updatedClassRight{
    position: absolute;
    top: 8px;
    right: 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.21/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

Shown Field : <input id="thedate" type="text" /><br />
Hidden Field : <input id="thealtdate" type="text" /><br />
<input id="thesubmit" type="button" value="Submit" />
```

Comment: Thanks, it works fine. But there is one issue. I am using minDate and maxDate. So can the next/prev be depressed when the navigation between months is not possible?

Answer (score 0):

I would just add more specific CSS rule in your CSS file, that should fix it. Starting point:

```
body .ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-prev,
body .ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-next {
    width: 2.6em;
}

body .ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-prev span.ui-icon.ui-icon-circle-triangle-w,
body .ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-next span.ui-icon.ui-icon-circle-triangle-e {
    background: none;
    overflow: visible;
    text-indent: 0;
    width: initial;
    left: 30%;
}
```